# Threejs rotate Multiple object with mouse move event

Tags: javascript, three.js

**I want rotate multiple object , but only one object can be rotate.**
Here is my code:

1.creatgeo fun

```
function createScene( geometry, scale, material ) {

geometry.computeTangents();

creatgeo = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

creatgeo.scale.x = creatgeo.scale.y = creatgeo.scale.z = scale;

scene.add( creatgeo );
```

}

2.use json loader in function init()

```
var jgdframe = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jgdframe.load( "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-frame.json", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, 1, framemat ) } );
var jgdlogo = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jgdlogo.load( "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-logo.json", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, 1, logomat ) } );
var jgdlight = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jgdlight.load( "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-light.json", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, 1, lightmat ) } );
```

3.add event in function init()

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
```

4.to render in function render()

```
function render() {

var ry = mouseX * 0.0003, rx = mouseY * 0.0003;

if( creatgeo ) {

    creatgeo.rotation.y = ry;
    creatgeo.rotation.x = rx;

};


camera.lookAt( scene.position );

renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

**I load three object in my sence, but only one object can be rotate. 
How fix it. thanks all !**

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code samples I can point out a few corrections:

- The variable named `creatgeo` is not pre-initialized. This makes it leak in the global scope were it gets overwritten everytime you invoke the function `createScene()`. That's why only the last loaded object is animated.
- You should declare any variable before assigning any value to them: `var creatgeo;`. This makes the variable available only in the function's local scope. Though this doesn't suffice to solve your problem. You need to declare an Array or an Object in wich you will cache all the models loaded by the jsonLoader.

Something like this should work:

```
var objects = []; // I suggest renaming "creatgeo" to "objects"

function updateScene( id, geometry, scale, material ) {
    geometry.computeTangents();
    objects[id]= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    objects[id].scale.x = objects[id].scale.y = objects[id].scale.z = scale;
    scene.add( objects[id] );
}
```

- Also take note that you don't need to create a loader each time you load an object, this is inefficient and slows down the browser at load time, also more memory then necessary gets allocated.
- Observe that you can use custom materials defined by the exporter tool in your json objects. Use the loader materials if your models have materials defined. If not leave it as is.

Example:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

jsonLoader.load( 
    "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-frame.json", 
    function( geometry, material ) { 
        createScene( 0, geometry, 1, framemat ) 
    });

jsonLoader.load( 
    "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-logo.json", 
    function( geometry, material ) { 
        createScene( 1, geometry, 1, logomat ) 
    });

jsonLoader.load( 
    "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-light.json", 
    function( geometry, material ) { 
        createScene( 2, geometry, 1, lightmat ) 
    });
```

- You can take this further by incrementing the id's using a loop and retrieving the path strings from an array.
- Observe the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). This is absolutelly necessary in this kind of construct. The IIFE creates a closure in wich the id is preserved at it's current iteration. Otherwise, all the loaders will receive the last value of the incremented id messing up the code.

Example:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    paths = [
        "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-frame.json", 
        "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-logo.json", 
        "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-light.json"
    ],
    objNum = paths.length; // Cache obects.length


for ( var id = 0; id < paths.length; id++ ) {
    (function(){ // IIFE start

        // Basic loader
        jsonLoader.load( paths[id], 
            function( geometry, material ) { 
                createScene( id, geometry, 1, material ) 
            }
        );

    })(); // IIFE end
}
```

- Finally you need to animate each object.

This goes in the render loop:

```
for ( var id = 0; id < objNum; id++ ) {
    if( objects[id] ) {
        objects[id].position.set(x, y, z);
        objects[id].rotation.set(rx, ry, rz);
    }
}
```